# How to stub a delete association to return false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stubbing

I have `dealer.cars` where a dealer has many cars.
In my spec i want to stub `dealer.cars.delete(car)` to return false. However i cannot get this to work.
I have currently tried:

`allow_any_instance_of(Car).to receive(:delete).and_return(false)`

`expect(dealer.cars).to receive(:delete).with(car).and_return(false)`

However in my code when running the spec it is still returning true.

Comment: Is `dealer.cars` returning `Car`? Figure out what `dealer.cars.class` is.

Comment: yes it is returning `Car`

Comment: If this is a Rails association, it might report to be `Car` but actually be something else. Rails does some shenanigans to make it seem like `Car` but is, fundamentally, another thing entirely.

Comment: `dealer.cars` is not an instance of `Car`, and `expect(dealer.cars).to receive....` won't work, because each time you call `dealer.cars`, you're returning a *different object* - so the object you're stubbing isn't the same object that's being used in the code.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this code? "I want to stub `dealer.cars.delete`" isn't a problem, it's a solution. Whilst there are some hacky ways you may get this to work, there may be an entirely different solution you're not considering -- because you're asking for help on a solution, instead of asking about the original problem. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/369864

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `cars` is a `has_many` association on the `Dealer` model then no, `cars` won't be returning an instance of `Car`, it'll be returning a collection instance of class `Car::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` - so if you wanted to use the `allow_any_instance_of`, then you'd need to use that.

But a much better way to mock a chain of calls is:

```
expect(dealer).to receive_message_chain(:cars, :delete) { false }
```

Comment: I just discovered `receive_message_chain`! Awesome. Thanks!